# Can Event Receiver be used in Sharepoint Client Object Model 2010?

Tags: client-object-model, event-receivers, event-handlers

I need to e.g detect in a console application any updates that affect items in a SP list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have event receiver in client object model, Pls check the MSDN documentation on the SP.List object: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554951).

But yes if you want to do the same using Server object model in Console application...it is possible. To detect the changes you can attach event receiver on the List in the event you want and then either you can log the changes based on your need or debug the application to get the changes.

Comment: Pushpendra, can you further explain.. As I didn't see the question was answered by your post!